On the vanishing of a polynomial with coefficients related to the Gauss hypergeometric function
I recently asked a question about resolving a conjecture I had on the solution set of the ODE
$$(a^2-1)Q''(a) + \left(3a-\frac{d-1}{a} \right)Q'(a) + \frac{3}{4}Q(a)=0,$$
obtained by looking for certain radial, self similar solutions to a nonlinear wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}.$ After doing a search on the OEIS, the user Fred Hucht kindly suggested that for $d=2n+3, n=0, 1, 2, \ldots, $ the solution set is the span of $\{P_n(a), P_n(-a)\}$, where
$$P_n(a)=a^{-2n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} 
\binom{n}{k} \, {}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-k;-2n;2)(1-a)^{n+1/2} a^k.$$
Indeed, for any such fixed small $n$, one can check via Mathematica that $P_n$ satisfies the given ODE, and hence so does $P_n(-a)$.
However, I would like to rigorously show that indeed $P_n(a)$ is a solution for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ without needing to check it on Mathematica. Naturally, I substituted the form of $P_n(a)$ into the ODE, and after some help simplifying the expression, I reduced the problem to showing that
$$F(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 
\binom{n}{k} \, {}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-k;-2n;2)a^k\left( a^2 k^2-2 a^2 k n+a^2 k+a^2 n^2-a^2 n+2 a k n+a k-2 a n^2-a n-k^2+2 k n+k\right)=0 $$
for all such $a$ that the ODE is satisfied.
It suffices therefore to show that $F^{(m)}(0)=0$ for $0\le m\le n+2$. We may check by hand that $F(0)=0, F'(0)=0$ using the fact that ${}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,0;-2n;2)=1, {}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-1;-2n;2)=\frac{2n+1}{2n}$. To continue, it would help if we had an explicit expression for ${}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-k;-2n;2)$ where $0\le k\le n+2$, however Mathematica does not return a closed form result for generic $k$, though it seems that for each such $k$, ${}_2F_1(\tfrac 1 2,-k;-2n;2)$ is a ratio of two polynomials of order $k$ in $n$ with integer coefficients. Note that since the hypergeometric function has two inputs that are negative integers in the second and third position, it does not reduce to a finite sum.
If this is too difficult, I would also be happy with simply showing that for each $n$, there exists constants $c(n,k)$ such that
$$G_c(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 
\binom{n}{k} \, c(n,k) \, a^k\left( a^2 k^2-2 a^2 k n+a^2 k+a^2 n^2-a^2 n+2 a k n+a k-2 a n^2-a n-k^2+2 k n+k\right)\equiv 0 .$$
This itself may be reduced to computing the determinant of a certain matrix related to the above coefficients.

You can write
$$P_n(a)=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1/2}(1+a)^n}{a^{2n+1}},{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}-n,1/2\-2n\end{matrix};\frac{2a}{1+a}\right).$$
To see this, simply change the order of summation in the expression you have and use the binomial theorem. Isn't your differential equation just the standard hypergeometric equation for this function?

Can you elaborate on your second sentence? From what I have read about the hypergeometric differential equation, the equation in my post is not standard, though it does becomes once one substitutes $a\mapsto \sqrt{a}$.

No problem. I checked that your equation is indeed the hypergeometric equation (up to a change of variable) and wrote it in more detail as an answer.

We can write
\begin{align*}P_n(a)&=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1/2}}{a^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk a^k\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(1/2)_j(-k)_j}{j!(-2n)_j}2^j\\
&=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1/2}}{a^{2n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(1/2)_j}{j!(-2n)_j}(-2)^j
\sum_{k=j}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-j)!}a^k\\
&=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1/2}}{a^{2n+1}}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{(1/2)_j(-n)_j}{j!(-2n)_j}(2a)^j(1+a)^{n-j}\\
&=\frac{(1-a)^{n+1/2}(1+a)^n}{a^{2n+1}}\,{}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}-n,1/2\\-2n\end{matrix};\frac{2a}{1+a}\right),\tag{1}\end{align*}
where we first changed the order of summation and then computed the sum over $k$ using the binomial theorem. Now let
$$f(x)={}_2F_1\left(\begin{matrix}-n,1/2\\-2n\end{matrix};x\right).$$
This function satisfies the hypergeometric differential equation
$$x(1-x)f''+\left(\left(n-\frac 32\right)x-2n\right)f'+\frac n2\, f=0.\tag{2}$$
Inverting the relation (1) gives
$$f(x)=\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1/2}(x-1)^{n+1/2}(x-2)^{1/2}}\,P_n\left(\frac x{2-x}\right).\tag{3}$$
Substituting (3) in (2) gives after simplification
$$(a^2-1)P_n''+\left(3a-\frac{2n+2}{a}\right)P_n'+\frac 34\,P_n=0.$$
This proves that $Q=P_n$ indeed solves your differential equation, with $d=2n+3$.
